# Setting Indicators of modified files in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

Is there a way to set indicators of git modified lines in a file in Android Studio? I haven't used Android Studio before and now I want to set up such functionality like it was in VsCode(also known as Gutter Indicators - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_gutter-indicators)

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

> File > Settings > Version Control > Confirmation > Gutter